# How to fix error Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:0) of '_GrowableList'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a little card "game", and for now am trying to simply reset my card List when user hits the available button.

I'm having the following error message when hitting the "Reiniciar" button. I've tried to reinitialize just by stating `_cardsAux=_cards` but it does nothing...So I tried `_cardsAux.addAll(_cards)`, which returns the error. I know that if I hard code my cards list onto the cardAux variable, it works, but i don't want that...What can I do to fix this and reach the desired result of resetting the card list so the user can keep playing?

```
> ======== Exception caught by gesture =============================================================== The following ConcurrentModificationError was thrown while handling a
> gesture: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:0)
> of '_GrowableList'.
> 
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
> #0      List.addAll (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:215:11)
> #1      _MyHomePageState._getACard.<anonymous closure> (package:our_cards/main.dart:102:29)
> #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1269:30)
> #3      _MyHomePageState._getACard (package:our_cards/main.dart:96:5)
> #4      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:our_cards/main.dart:163:36) ... Handler: "onTap" Recognizer:
> TapGestureRecognizer#3ba91   debugOwner: GestureDetector   state:
> possible   won arena   finalPosition: Offset(218.7, 456.4)  
> finalLocalPosition: Offset(60.4, 25.6)   button: 1   sent tap down
```

my main.dart code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

int  random(min, max){
  var rn = new Random();
  return min + rn.nextInt(max - min);
}
final _cards = [
  {'card':'Card A'},
  {'card':'Card B'},
  {'card':'Card C'}
];
var _card ='Press arrow Icon below to Start';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Our Cards',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Our Cards'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;


  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int pop;
  var _cardsAux = _cards ;

  void _getACard(bool isReset) {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      if(isReset){_cardsAux.addAll(_cards);}
      if(_cardsAux.length== 0){
        _card = 'No More Cards';
      }
      else {
        pop = random(0, _cardsAux.length);
        _card = _cardsAux[pop]['card'];
        _cardsAux.removeAt(pop);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child:
                  Text('$_card',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                  )
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  onPressed: () => _getACard(true),
                  child: Text(
                    "Reiniciar",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () =>_getACard(false),
        tooltip: 'Next Card',
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I replaced the line >> _cardsAux.addAll(_cards); << with  >> _cardsAux = _cards; <<. Is this the expected result? The error was due to concurrent modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In your code, `_cardsAux` is `_cards` 
You can in `initState` call `_cardsAux = List.from(_cards);` 
code snippet

```
List<Map<String, String>> _cardsAux;

@override
  void initState() {
    _cardsAux = List.from(_cards);
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

int random(min, max) {
  var rn = new Random();
  return min + rn.nextInt(max - min);
}

final List<Map<String, String>> _cards = [
  {'card': 'Card A'},
  {'card': 'Card B'},
  {'card': 'Card C'}
];
var _card = 'Press arrow Icon below to Start';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Our Cards',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Our Cards'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int pop;
  List<Map<String, String>> _cardsAux;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _cardsAux = List.from(_cards);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _getACard(bool isReset) {
    setState(() {
      if (isReset) {
        _cardsAux.addAll(_cards);
      }
      if (_cardsAux.length == 0) {
        _card = 'No More Cards';
      } else {
        pop = random(0, _cardsAux.length);
        _card = _cardsAux[pop]['card'];
        print(_card);
        print("_cards ${_cards.length}");
        print("_cardsAux ${_cardsAux.length}");
        _cardsAux.removeAt(pop);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Text(
                  '$_card',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                )),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                onPressed: () => _getACard(true),
                child: Text(
                  "Reiniciar",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _getACard(false),
        tooltip: 'Next Card',
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Why have an initState method? I tried with ` List<Map<String, String>> _cardsAux = List.from(_cards);` and it also worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use ( Dart documentation: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/removeWhere.html )

```
Map.removeWhere((key, value) => toRemove.contains(key));
```